# Displaying the day name of a previous date in a Hive Query?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to display the day of a previous date. Please see the below. I am able to do this for the current date, but unable to use the date_sub function to get the day displayed of 3 days ago.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_timestamp),'EEEE');
+-----------+--+
|    _c0    |
+-----------+--+
| Thursday  |
+-----------+--+

select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_sub(current_timestamp,3)),'EEEE');
+-------+--+
|  _c0  |
+-------+--+
| NULL  |
+-------+--+
```

Is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select date_format(date_add(to_date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()), -3), 'EEEE');
```

You can change the '3' to the number of days you'd like to go back.
Try to avoid using 'unix_timestamp' as that function is being deprecated.

Comment: Perfect, this works, thank you! And I didn't know that about unix_timestamp, so I will avoid using that in the future. Thanks for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the number of seconds*num days  from `unix_timestamp` and then use the conversion.

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(current_date) - 3*86400,'EEEE')
```

Comment: How does that work in case Daylight Saving Time happens in between and one of these days have only 23 hours? Or 25 hours? In case one of these days is either 31-Dec or 30-Jun and happens to have a leap second...? Cf. https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time